# Hide newly released application temporarly for users in PROD

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, reverse-proxy, identityserver4

We use SSO for autentication of our users. Now we have released a new application only for pilot-testers to our production environment which uses SSO as well. The problem is if other users know the URL could log on to the new application, if they are already logged on to one of our applications.

How do we solve this that only pilot-testers can log on into the application?

Comment: Add authorization to only grant pilot-testers access, e.g. using a policy.

Comment: Where should we add the policies? Ont the IdP or om the newly released applikation? Could it affect pilot-tester? Can they still log on into the old applikations?

Comment: Authorisation is the responsibility of client application and not the identity server. It could be as simple as a whitelist of account IDs that only comes into play during the pilot phase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is short-circuit the pipeline when an invalid or unknown user wants to access the application. You can accomplish this with [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) or by adding a filter to the authorization component.

The easiest way may be to use [Claim-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for that. You'll only need to add a policy that looks for the presence of a claim.

The startup of the client could look something like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        // this sets up a default authorization policy for the application
        // in this case, authenticated users are required
        // (besides controllers/actions that have [AllowAnonymous])
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
               .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
               .RequireClaim("http://mynewapp.com/pilot-tester")
               .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });

    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.ClaimActions.MapAll();
        options.Scope.Add("mynewapp");

        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.ClientId = "mvc";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
    });
}
```

This will only grant access to pilot-testers. Please note that all code where the `AllowAnonymous` attribute is used, still will be available for everybody!

If you want to prevent access to these methods then you'll need to check the user with code, e.g.:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && 
    !User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "http://mynewapp.com/pilot-tester"))
    return Redirect("...");
```

*How to configure IdentityServer:*

When your app only is a website without other api's, then you'll need to add the claim to the Identity.

In the database make sure the following records are added (the values are examples):

AspNetUserClaims - add a claim for each user that is a pilot-tester. The type should be something you can use for the filter, like `http://mynewapp.com/pilot-tester` and value `true`.

IdentityResources - `mynewapp`. Corresponds with the requested scope.

IdentityClaims - `http://mynewapp.com/pilot-tester` (linked to IdentityResource `mynewapp`).

How this works:

The user is a resource with claims. In order to keep tokens small the claims are filtered by the claims that are part of the requested scopes: openid, profile and mynewapp.

All claims that match by type are included to the User.Identity.Claims collection, that is being used when testing the policy.

---

If you are using an API then you should protect that resource as well. Add a record to ApiResources `Api1`. The client application should request the scope:

```
options.Scope.Add("api1");
```

Please note that in this case ApiResource and ApiScope have the same name. But the relation between ApiResource and ApiScope is 1:n.

Add a record to the ApiClaims table (or ApiScope to narrow it):

ApiClaims - `http://mynewapp.com/pilot-tester` (linked to ApiResource `Api1`).

The user resource remains the same, but now IdentityServer will add the claim to the access token as well. *Register the policy in the api* in the same way as above.

---

Being temporary you may want to make the filters conditional, giving you the option to enable / disable the filter.

But you may not have to code at all. Being behind a proxy means that you can look at the filter options there first. You may want to filter on ip adress. This means that you can grant access to everybody from certain ip addresses, without having to change the application.

Comment: Thanks, If I sammerize your answer, we need to change only the new application and not somewhere in our IdP? and about the Filter options for IP-Addresses, If we add this kind of options for an IP-Address then they will not be able to access other applications neither?

Comment: The filter is only needed in the new application. It doesn't affect other applications. All that has to be done in the Idp is a matter of configuration. No code changes there. About the IP filter, if this is on host level (e.g. IIS) then the filter applies for the IIS application. Make sure the new application is hosted in a new IIS application. That way other applications are not affected by the filter. But... the pilot-testuser may be able to access existing applications. Prevent this using filters in the existing applications as well, e.g. a claim that grants access to the application.

Comment: We use an Reverse Proxy, which means we can adda filter there without changing code in the new application. So we add a filter based on Ip-Address (the pilot-testers IP-address). Am I right?

Comment: @user217648 Yes, that's what I meant with the last alinea of the answer. But this only works with fixed ip addresses / ranges. If you do not want a requirement on ip address you can use middleware / authorization filter to add more advanced authorization.

Comment: @user217648 Please note that the pilot-testuser still has to be authenticated. And being authenticated means having access to all applications that use the same IdP. So you may want add basic authorization to prevent users from accessing the 'invalid' app. You can add claims to a user and add policies to authorize users, as shown in the answer.